# Using salt stack to install a python module with pip from a git repo

Tags: git, pip, salt-stack

I have tried a number of things but have not had success installing a python package using pip.installed from a git repository. Ex.

```
include:
  - common/python-pip

spi:
  pip.installed:
    - bin_env: '/usr/bin/pip'
    - pkgs: git+https://github.com/GIT_HUB_USER/python-spi
    - require:
      - sls: common/python-pip
```

Has anyone had any success with this or do I just need to stop waiting for the package maintainer to accept pull requests and fork the package on PyPi?

Comment: Running Salt-Stack 2019.2.3

Comment: Please don't add additional info in comments. Use the edit button to add them to your question instead

Comment: Do you get any error message when you try to di it like this?

Answer (score 0):

The `pkgs` parameter should be in list format. So you can try this:

```
include:
  - common/python-pip

spi:
  pip.installed:
    - bin_env: '/usr/bin/pip'
    - pkgs: 
      - "git+https://github.com/GIT_HUB_USER/python-spi"
    - require:
      - sls: common/python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I was under pressure to get my project wrapped up as I was changing jobs so I ended up publishing my customized code to PyPi and installing as I would any other readily available library. For now I no longer have access to the Salt server so am unable to test further. Thanks Viet Do for your answer, sorry I didn't have a chance to test it out.